# SQL XML Insert multiple elements

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, xquery

Please help! I have a field of xml within a database.  I am trying to insert a new element for each element in the field. E.g:

```
<some-element>
<a> </a>
<b> </b>
</some-element>
<some-element>
<a> </a>
<b> </b>
</some-element>
```

would insert element c and go to:

```
<some-element>
<a> </a>
<b> </b>
<c> </c>
</some-element>
<some-element>
<a> </a>
<b> </b>
<c> </c>
</some-element>
```

I know I can use @fieldname.modify('insert @CElement into (/some-element)[1]') but this only changes the first element! I want to repeat this for all elements.

Any help would be very much appreciated! (I am using SQL server 2008)

**Moved from answer:**

Thank you for your reply! Perhaps it would help if I was more specific... I am describing a simple table of data within the xml. I am trying to add a new column. I can add the column within the column descriptions but I need to add the column element to all the rows. (It would not be a simple task to change the structure and I would like to avoid this!) E.g:

```
<Table> 
   <Columns> 
      <Column ID="0"> 
      <Column-Name>0NAME</Column-Name>
      </Column> 
      <Column ID="1"> 
      <Column-Name>1NAME</Column-Name> 
      </Column> 
      <Column ID="2"> 
      <Column-Name>2NAME</Column-Name> 
      </Column> 
      <Column ID="3"> 
      <Column-Name>!!!! THIS COLUMN IS BEING ADDED !!!!!</Column-Name> 
      </Column> 
   </Columns>
 <Rows>
        <Row ID="0">
          <C ID="0">0 contents here</C>
          <C ID="1">0 contents here</C>
          <C ID="2">0 contents here</C>
          <!-- NEW COLUMN NEEDS TO BE CREATED HERE -->
         </Row>
        <Row ID="1">
          <C ID="0">1 contents here</C>
          <C ID="1">1 contents here</C>
          <C ID="2">1 contents here</C>
          <!-- NEW COLUMN NEEDS TO BE CREATED HERE -->
        </Row>
    <Row ID="2">
          <C ID="0">2 contents here</C>
          <C ID="1">2 contents here</C>
          <C ID="2">2 contents here</C>
          <!-- NEW COLUMN NEEDS TO BE CREATED HERE -->
        </Row>
</Rows>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate your XML, e.g.:

```
declare @x xml = '<some-element>
<a>1</a>
<b>2</b>
</some-element>
<some-element>
<a>3</a>
<b>4</b>
</some-element>'

select @x.query
('
   for $e in some-element
   return
     <some-element>
      { $e/a }
      { $e/b }
      <c/>
     </some-element>
')
```

Comment: I have tried this solution in several ways, though I can not get it to work for my data! A full description of the data is shown in a post below - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9931812/569436) provided by [Kirill Polishchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/787016/kirill-polishchuk) to the new XML structure:

```
select @XML.query
('
   for $c in Table/Columns
   return
     <Table>
       <Columns>
         { $c/* }
       </Columns>
       <Rows>
         { 
           for $r in Table/Rows/Row
           return
             <Row>
               { $r/* }
               <C ID="3"/>
             </Row>
         }
       </Rows>
     </Table>
')
```